# Display the mouse pointer trails... of the future!

Tags: popularity-contest, graphical-output

Inspired by [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298) of using [d3js](http://d3js.org/), I challenge you to create a canvas (or your language-of-choice equivalent) in which the [mouse pointer trails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(graphical_user_interfaces)#Pointer_trails_and_animation) will be displayed, with the following twist:

## The Twist

You should not display the trails of where the mouse pointer **was**, but the "trails" of where it **will** (might) be in future.

You can do it by using either:

1. A time machine, or
2. Probabilistic estimations based on previous mouse
   movements

## Assumptions

In case you didn't choose the time machine implementation, when the mouse does not move for more than *threshold* milliseconds, you can display none of the trails. (The *threshold* value is up to you to choose).

The cursor image is up to you and does not have to be the same of the OS's cursor (you can even draw a plain small circles or dots).

No evil input will be tested: You can assume the movements are smooth. 'Smooth' definition for this case is: if the mouse movements were a function over the x and y axis of the canvas - it would be a continuous function.

## Winning

<strike>The valid answer with the least characters in code will win. In case of a tie - the one that was posted first will win.</strike>

**EDIT:** The valid answer with the **most upvotes** will win. In case of a tie - the one that was posted first will win. You can be creational on the implementation, or be precise with the prediction. I'm not the judge anymore, we all are :)

- A valid answer must include a way for me to play with (test! I meant test), either on an online tool or on a freely-downloadable compiler/interpreter/runtime/etc.

Comment: I think this question might be better suited to a popularity contest than a code-golf, because it's fairly subjective as to what qualifies as a good enough prediction. I would recommend clarifying that or changing the tag. Nevertheless, looks fun.

Comment: You're right. I edited the question and changed the tag.

Comment: Time for someone to implement machine learning algorithms!

Comment: For testing purposes, which models of time machine do you have access to? And may we use standard libraries to interface with them?

Comment: Just a mathematician whining here: smooth != continuous. In fact wild spikey movement will still be continuous.

Comment: @CompuChip, you're absolutely right. And [Weierstrass Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) can prove it. However, I didn't want to dive into Calculus here, just wanted to give a plain explanation for programmers who are not necessarily mathematicians.

Comment: Tip! When the cursor goes up it must go down at some point.

Comment: Actually, since your mouse can be at only integer pair coordinates, a continuous function is impossible. I'm actually not really sure what you mean? That the next point must be "touching(in one of the 8 directions, or not moving)" the last?

Comment: @PeterTaylor My time machine uses GPIO pins. I decided that was too much of a hassle to deal with though.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Javascript

My program predicts the direction of the pointer by using the average of the angular change in direction of the last 20 mouse moves.  It also uses the variance of the angular change to create a "cloud" of possible locations and directions of the pointer.  The color of each pointer in the "cloud" is supposed to represent the likelihood of it being the new position of the mouse pointer, where darker colors represents a greater likelihood.  The distance of the pointer cloud ahead of the mouse is calculated using the speed of mouse movement.  It doesn't make the best predictions but it looks neat.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hs64t7w/4/

Increasing the size of the pointer cloud is interesting to see. It can be set by changing the `cloudSize` variable on the first line of the program. Here is a fiddle with a cloud size of 10: http://jsfiddle.net/5hs64t7w/5/

I used these sources to get formulas for circular mean and variance:
Circular Mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_mean
Circular Variance: http://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/software/PROCHECK/nmr_manual/man_cv.html

Here is the code if anyone is interested:

```
    var cloudSize = 3;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_element');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var prevX = -1;
    var prevY = -1;
    var curX = -1;
    var curY = -1;
    var distance = 0;
    var direction = 0;

    function drawMouse(x, y, angle, gray){
        var grayVal = Math.round(gray*255);
        var grayString = "rgb(" + grayVal + "," + grayVal +"," + grayVal + ")";
        c.fillStyle = grayString;
        c.strokeStyle = grayString;
        c.lineWidth = 1;
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(x, y);
        c.lineTo(x + 16*Math.cos(angle + Math.PI/2.0 + Math.PI/8.0), y + 16*Math.sin(angle + Math.PI/2.0 + Math.PI/8.0));
        c.moveTo(x, y);
        c.lineTo(x + 16*Math.cos(angle + Math.PI/2.0 - Math.PI/8.0), y + 16*Math.sin(angle + Math.PI/2.0 - Math.PI/8.0));
        c.lineTo(x + 16*Math.cos(angle + Math.PI/2.0 + Math.PI/8.0), y + 16*Math.sin(angle + Math.PI/2.0 + Math.PI/8.0));
        c.stroke();
        c.fill();
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(x, y);
        c.lineTo(x + 24*Math.cos(angle + Math.PI/2), y + 24*Math.sin(angle + Math.PI/2));
        c.stroke();
    }

    function sum(array){
        var s = 0.0;
        for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            s += array[i];
        }
        return s;
    }

    var sins = [];
    var coss = [];
    var lengths = [];
    var times = [];
    var index = 0;
    var limit = 20;
    var variance = 0;
    var prevTime = new Date().getTime();
    function updateDistanceAndDirection(x, y){
        var angle = Math.atan2(prevY - curY, prevX - curX);
        sins[index] = Math.sin(angle);
        coss[index] = Math.cos(angle);
        lengths[index] = Math.sqrt((curX-prevX)*(curX-prevX) + (curY-prevY)*(curY-prevY));
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        times[index] = time - prevTime;

        variance = 1.0 - Math.sqrt(sum(coss)*sum(coss)+sum(sins)*sum(sins))/sins.length;

        direction = Math.atan2(1/sins.length*sum(sins),1/coss.length*sum(coss));
        var speed = sum(lengths)/(sum(times)/200);
        distance = Math.min(Math.max(40, speed), 100);
        prevTime = time;
        index = (index+1)%limit;
    }

    function drawMice(count){
        c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for(var i=count; i>=0; i--){
            var dir = direction + i*variance;
            drawMouse(curX - distance*Math.cos(dir), curY - distance*Math.sin(dir), dir - Math.PI/2, i/count);
            dir = direction - i*variance;
            drawMouse(curX - distance*Math.cos(dir), curY - distance*Math.sin(dir), dir - Math.PI/2, i/count);
        }
    }

    canvas.onmousemove = function (event) {
        curX = event.clientX;
        curY = event.clientY;

        updateDistanceAndDirection(curX, curY);

        drawMice(cloudSize);

        prevX = curX;
        prevY = curY;
    };
```

Comment: Can you display a sequence of mouse pointer (with fixed orientation) instead of a pointer pointing to variable direction? I was expecting to see "mouse trails" but can't see any, haha

Comment: Very nice, but isn't it more plausible that the pointer should go up in the future when it currently goes down? Imho, the program should do exactly the opposite so the it predicts the pointer stays on screen.

Comment: @MennoGouw its not perfect but its pretty damned good

Comment: @nimchimpsky Just saying the probability of the mouse going up is higher if the mouse currently goes down. The program itself is great.

Comment: Do you think it's also possible to use the usual human behavior for mouse handling ? Like circles, straight lines... These could be predicted even further in the future (calculating the radius of the circle after a couple mesures, and finishing the circle even before you drafted it)

Comment: It always points to the left. (Safari 7.0.6, OS X 10.9)

Answer (score 14):

## Java

I decided to take the time machine approach. It turns out the key ingredient of a time machine is java.awt.Robot. My program lets you move your mouse around for 10 seconds. After the 10 seconds it goes back in time and recreates your mouse movement, while predicting it perfectly.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class TimeMachine extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

    Timer timer;
    int time = 10;
    java.util.Timer taskTimer;
    ArrayList<Point> mousePoints;
    ArrayList<Long> times;
    Robot robot;
    int width, height;
    ArrayList<Point> drawMousePoints;

    public TimeMachine(){
        width = 500;
        height = 500;
        drawMousePoints = new ArrayList<Point>();

        robot = null;
        try{
            robot = new Robot();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("The time machine malfunctioned... Reverting to 512 BC");
        }
        mousePoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
        times = new ArrayList<Long>();

        taskTimer = new java.util.Timer();

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                time--;
                if(time == 0)
                    rewind();
                repaint();
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer(1000, al);
        start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.drawString("Time Machine activiates in: " + time, 15, 50);
        for(int i=0; i<drawMousePoints.size(); i++){
            Point drawMousePoint = drawMousePoints.get(i);
            drawMouse(drawMousePoint.x-getLocationOnScreen().x, drawMousePoint.y-getLocationOnScreen().y, g, Color.BLACK, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, (double)i/drawMousePoints.size());
        }
    }

    public void drawMouse(int x, int y, Graphics g, Color line, Color fill, double alpha){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setColor(new Color(fill.getRed(), fill.getGreen(), fill.getBlue(), (int)Math.max(Math.min(alpha*255, 255), 0)));
        g2d.fillPolygon(new int[]{x, x, x+4, x+8, x+10, x+7, x+12}, new int[]{y, y+16, y+13, y+20, y+19, y+12, y+12}, 7);

        g2d.setColor(new Color(line.getRed(), line.getGreen(), line.getBlue(), (int)Math.max(Math.min(alpha*255, 255), 0)));
        g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y + 16);
        g2d.drawLine(x, y+16, x+4, y+13);
        g2d.drawLine(x+4, y+13, x+8, y+20);
        g2d.drawLine(x+8, y+20, x+10, y+19);
        g2d.drawLine(x+10, y+19, x+7, y+12);
        g2d.drawLine(x+7, y+12, x+12, y+12);
        g2d.drawLine(x+12, y+12, x, y);
    }

    public void start(){
        timer.start();
        prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mousePoints.clear();
    }

    public void rewind(){
        timer.stop();
        long timeSum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<times.size(); i++){
            timeSum += times.get(0);
            final boolean done = i == times.size()-1;
            taskTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                    Point point = mousePoints.remove(0);
                    drawMousePoints.clear();
                    drawMousePoints.addAll(mousePoints.subList(0, Math.min(mousePoints.size(), 30)));
                    robot.mouseMove(point.x, point.y);
                    repaint();
                    if(done)
                        System.exit(0);
                }
            }, timeSum);
        }
    }

    long prevTime = 0;
    public void record(MouseEvent m){
        if(timer.isRunning()){
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mousePoints.add(new Point(m.getXOnScreen(), m.getYOnScreen()));
            times.add((time-prevTime)/10);
            prevTime = time;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        TimeMachine timeMachine = new TimeMachine();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Time Machine");
        frame.setSize(timeMachine.width, timeMachine.height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(timeMachine);

        frame.add(timeMachine);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m) {
        record(m);
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m) {
        record(m);
    }

}
```

Comment: Code slightly optimized by Netbeans (got rid of the warnings): http://pastebin.com/E57LZ4zY

Answer (score 10):

## Vanilla Javascript

Just to get things started, here is a simple prediction based on two values. The last `n` mouse postions are memorized and kept in a queue, the prediction is a simple linear extrapolation of the first and last element in the queue.

This is just the prediction code, the full code including the demo can be seen in <kbd>[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfyruc14/5/)</kbd>:

```
function predict(trail) {
    var b = trail.pop(),
        a = trail[0],
        d = {
            x: b.x - a.x,
            y: b.y - a.y
        },
        m = Math.sqrt( d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y );

    d.x = 5 * d.x / m;
    d.y = 5 * d.y / m;

    var predictions = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        predictions.push({
            x: b.x + i * d.x,
            y: b.y + i * d.y
        });
    }

    return predictions;
}
```

The demo contains a comment in the prediction that allows you to instead use the last two elements in the queue for the prediction. Makes the result more "real-time", but also less "smooth".

If anyone wants to use the <kbd>[boilerplate work](http://jsfiddle.net/pfyruc14/2/)</kbd> to implement a different prediction algorithm, feel free. It's not a lot of work anyway.

Comment: Can you display a mouse pointer instead of a line? I was expecting to see "mouse trails" but can't see any, haha

Comment: The question says it doesn't have to be a cursor ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Javascript**

*The past is the best prediction for the future* - me, and propably someone else too

My solution is very simple. First, here is the [>>> Fiddle! <<<](http://jsfiddle.net/k2zzz024/8/)

All it does is shifting the past trail, so it looks like the future trail. Basically no Math is involved (I Know, pretty boring). You can easily see the errors, especially when moving the cursor in circles. That's why I made the trail so short ;)

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .cursor {
                width: 12px;
                height: 19px;
                position: absolute;
                background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/h8imKBP.png);
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var x, y;
            window.onmousemove = function(e) {x=e.clientX; y=e.clientY;}

            var p = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
            window.setInterval(function() {
                p.shift();
                p.push([x, y]);
                var diff = [x-p[0][0], y-p[0][1]];
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    var e = document.getElementById(i);
                    e.style.left = (p[9-i][0]+diff[0])+"px";
                    e.style.top = (p[9-i][1]+diff[1])+"px";
                }
            }, 10);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="0" class="cursor"></div>
    <div id="1" class="cursor"></div>
    <div id="2" class="cursor"></div>
    <div id="3" class="cursor"></div>
    <div id="4" class="cursor"></div>
    <div id="5" class="cursor"></div>
    <div id="6" class="cursor"></div>
    <div id="7" class="cursor"></div>
    <div id="8" class="cursor"></div>
    <div id="9" class="cursor"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: haha I just had a look at the date. Whatever, I like it